# Qiskit implementation of Brassard Amplitude implementaion's Q operator

Tags: qiskit, amplitude-amplification

In Brassard's et al. work, the $Q$ operator is defined as

$$ Q =-\mathcal{A}\mathcal{S_0}\mathcal{A}^{-1}\mathcal{S_\chi}$$

I was wondering how is the negative sign at the leftmost side implemented within the operators in a quantum circuit? I already have a realization for  $S_\chi$, $S_0$ and $\mathcal{A}$. I can think of it as a basic sign flip using a one qubit operator with -1 in the diagonals but I am not sure if that's a correct implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The minus sign is a global phase. It can be ommited in case of operator $Q$ itself, however, it has to be included in controlled version of the operator.

Controlled global phase is implemented by gate (I assume IBM Q environment) $U1 \otimes I$, where $U1$ gate acts on control qubit and identity operator on target qubit.

$U1$ gate is given by matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & \mathrm{e}^{i\varphi}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

In your case $\varphi = \pi$ which leads to gate
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which is actually $Z$ gate.

**To sum up: you do not have bother about sign in case of operator $Q$ itself, in case of controlled operator $Q$, simply put $Z$ gate on control qubit.**

Comment: I see! Totally makes sense. thanks!

Comment: @CesarLeonardoClementeLópez: I am glad I helped. If the answer is ok for you, could you please accept it?

Answer (score 1):

As per the description in Brassard paper page 5 " ... Operator S<sub>x</sub> conditionally changes the sign of the amplitudes of the good states ....while the S<sub>0</sub> operator changes the sign of the amplitude if and only if the state is the zero state |0>. ..."

The amplitude is multiplied by e<sup>iƟ</sup> -> S<sub>x</sub>(Ɵ=φ) and S<sub>0</sub> (Ɵ=ϕ) .. as given in Theorem 4 further considered in Lemma 5, to pick  φ = ϕ = π which leads to Z gate

This is well explained in https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/grover.html
Brassard is a generalized version of Grover.